# Controlling for a variable when estimating interaction effects

Tags: interaction, causality, predictor, controlling-for-a-variable

Consider the relationships among four variables: `sex`, `activity`, `height`, and `weight`, as depicted below:

[image]

Suppose that `weight` is the response variable. When `sex` serves as the predictor, there is no need to control for any covariates. However, when `activity` is the predictor, we should include both `sex` and `height` as covariates.

Here are my questions (with the understanding that `weight` is always the response variable):

(1) When `height` is the predictor, what variable(s) should we control for?

(2) Suppose we wish to estimate the interaction effect between `sex` and `activity` ("Do the two sexes differ in the association between `activity` and `weight`?"). Should we control for `height` in this scenario?

(3) Suppose we wish to estimate the interaction effect between `sex` and `height` ("Do the two sexes differ in the association between `height` and `weight`?"). Should we control for `activity` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

1. You must control for sex, because it sets up a backdoor path, and is hence a confounding variable. You should NOT control for activity, because some of the causal effect of height on weight is mediated through activity.
2. For sex and activity interaction, you should include height because it is a backdoor path to the combined cause {sex, activity}.
3. For the sex and height interaction, there's no need to include activity, because it is not a confounder. However, it's possible you might get more precision by including it, since it does directly influence the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to clarify, for both questions (2) and (3), `weight` always remains the response/outcome variable. These two questions are specifically centered around the respective interaction effects on `weight`. Considering this clarification, would your answer change?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks! With one exposure, it is easy to understand the situation. However, I still have trouble handling an interaction effect between two exposures and determining how to control for a variable when two exposures are involved. Any literature about this topic? Is there a way to figure this out using, for example, the R package `dagitty`?

Comment: Here is your answer to question (2): "For sex and activity interaction, you should include height because it is a backdoor path to the combined cause {sex, activity}." I'm confused about this because `height` also acts as a mediator between `sex` and `weight`. In this case, should we avoid using it as a covariate for the interaction between `sex` and `activity` on `weight`?

Comment: That's a good question. I think I would still include (that is, control for) `height`, even if you choke off some of the causal effect of the mediator, and here's why: you would still get the specific effect of `sex` and `activity` on `weight` while avoiding confounding. This seems to me a better way of getting at the interaction of `sex` and `activity` than not including `height`. But I have no other, more fundamental way of thinking about this case.